# How to measure availability of a background process running as a WebJob?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, availability

We do not have any api endpoints exposed for the service, wondering if there is any standard way to do it through azure.

Comment: Have you considered looking at enabling Diagnostic Logs and setting up an alert  under Log Analytics? See: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs]

Comment: Yes, we do have Diagnostic logs enabled and log analytics too, but we need the metrics for availability to be present on a single dashboard at a single place (having metrics for other components too). And currently our webjob does not have any ping endpoint.

Comment: What is your definition of available? Is your web job triggered by an external event or is it running continuously? If so, what does it do? Are you able to log something on a regular basis?

Comment: Great questions, @PeterBons. Having the metrics displayed on a single dashboard can still be achieved by other means but first you'll need to define how to get the availability depending on the type of job - and what kind of metrics you would need to cross-query indirectly to get what you need. I would assume that those which are continuously running would be easier to monitor...

Comment: @PeterBons This is a continuously running job that reads incoming messages from a Service bus topic and processes them. We do have logs for message received and other processing but we do not have a guarantee on constant incoming load. 

By availability I mean, whether my service is up and in a healthy state to process messages (whether it is processing the messages properly will be later measured as part of reliability).

Comment: One option is to create a timer and log some activity so you can create an alert based on the absence of those logs for a given period.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as mentioned in the comment, you can create a timer and log some activity so you can create an alert based on the absence of those logs for a given period.